# How to add remove ads button in action bar in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

So, basically, I want to add a Remove ads button in my action bar which would on click open a paid version of my app in the play store.

I have made the design pretty much but don't know how to implement it in code.

[image: Design of the action bar]

I would be thankful to anyone who could teach me how to do it.

Here is my code;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAsync.MyAsyncInterface, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

```
// Log
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

// Constants
public static final String EXTRA_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION = "disable_notification";

// Layout
private View rootView;
private MySwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private InfoView infoView;

// Catalog
private CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter;
private Catalog catalog;

// Broadcast listener
private final IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(SyncManager.ACTION_SYNC);
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            int result = intent.getIntExtra(SyncManager.EXTRA_RESULT, SyncManager.RESULT_FAIL);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); // Stop refresh layout
            if (result == SyncManager.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                // Reload local content
                if (loadLocalContent()) {
                    refreshList();
                } else {
                    // This error is very unlikely to happen
                    showCatalogDownloadError();
                }
            } else if (result == SyncManager.RESULT_TIMEOUT) {
                // Connection timeout
                showTimeoutError();
            } else {
                // Catalog sync failed
                showCatalogDownloadError(); // Show catalog download error
            }
        }
    }
};

private Context context;
private Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // Layout
    rootView = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    GridView catalogList = findViewById(R.id.catalog_grid);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (MySwipeRefreshLayout) rootView;
    infoView = findViewById(R.id.info_view);

    // Swipe down refresh
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setSwipeableChildren(R.id.catalog_grid);

    // Catalog list
    catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(this);
    catalog = new Catalog();
    catalogList.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);
    catalogList.setOnItemClickListener(catalogItemClickListener);

    // Before anything check if the sensors are available
    boolean checkSensors = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_CHECKSENS, PREF_CHECKSENS_DEFAULT);
    if (!Utils.sensorsAvailable(this) && checkSensors) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(R.string.main_dialog_nosensor_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.main_dialog_nosensor_message)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.common_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(PREF_CHECKSENS, false).apply();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    infoView.show(R.string.main_info_empty_title, R.string.main_info_empty_message);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Register broadcast listener
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);

    // Check if refresh is running without service
    if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing() && !SyncManager.isRunning()) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    // Load catalog if available
    loadLocalContent();
    refreshList();

    // Check if catalog is expired
    InternalData internalData = new InternalData(this);
    long lastTimestamp = internalData.readLong(LD_TIMESTAMP, 0);
    long delta = getTimestamp() - lastTimestamp;

    if (delta < 0 || delta > T_CATALOG_EXPIRATION || catalog.size() == 0) {
        // Catalog has expired download
        Log.d(TAG, "Catalog has reached expiration");
        loadRemoteContent();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Catalog is still valid!");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

// Download Listener
@Override
public void onCompleted(int id, Bundle extra) {
    if (id == WallpaperDownloader.ID) {
        CatalogItem downloadedItem = extra.getParcelable(WallpaperDownloader.EXTRA_CATALOG_ITEM);
        startSetActivity(downloadedItem);
        refreshList(); // refresh list for downloaded icon
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to to where ?

Comment: In the action bar. I have attached a picture with the question.

Comment: Can you share your ads code please

Comment: I have updated my question with the code check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *Solved!*

**Here is how I solved it;**

### I just made a new layout and activity and added a button with the link to the paid version of the app on the play store.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_remove_ads);
}
public void premium (View view){
    openUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app");
}
public void openUrl(String url)
{
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchWeb=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    startActivity(launchWeb);
}
```

### **Here is the layout I made;**

[image]

*I can provide all the drawables and code if requested.
Hope this helps someone else new in Android Development like me :)*